# Java: threads of pool get blocked without finishing work

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, java-threads

I have a "blocked thread" problem. Let me explain how this application work. This is a file processor, it reads files from directories, do something with them and writes an output to another directory. It has threads that read files from different directories an add them to queues. Each of this "reading thread" has an ExecutorService built with Executors.newFixedThreadPool(someNumber) of threads that consumes files from queues, process them and write the output.

For example, now is configured in this way:

- ReadingThread1 with 2 ProcessingThreads (pool-2-thread-x)
- ReadingThread2 with 5 ProcessingThreads (pool-3-thread-x)
- ReadingThread3 with 1 ProcessingThread (pool-4-thread-1)
- ReadingThread4 with 1 ProcessingThread (pool-5-thread-1)

This application has been working for years and now I added another behavior to the file processing. The problem is that after many hours (sometimes 6, 8 or 20 hours) of running some of the threads get blocked and we have to rollback to the previous version.

This two threads were blocked more or less at the same time.

```
Name: pool-4-thread-1
State: WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@64336985
Total blocked: 512  Total waited: 7,797

Stack trace: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Last logged line:
13:32:49:830 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG ClassB:79 - MessageB

Name: pool-2-thread-2
State: WAITING on     java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@65ffe5b2
Total blocked: 528  Total waited: 7,795

Stack trace: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Last logged line:
13:35:18:997 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO  ClassA:110 - MessageA
```

This three threads were blocked more or less at the same time.

```
Name: pool-3-thread-1
State: WAITING on     java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2d9e6700
Total blocked: 1,506  Total waited: 7,421

Stack trace: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Last logged line:
11:55:22:477 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  ClassA:110 - MessageA


Name: pool-3-thread-4
State: WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2d9e6700
Total blocked: 1,969  Total waited: 7,456

Stack trace: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Last logged line:
11:55:03:962 [pool-3-thread-4] INFO  ClassA:110 - MessageA


Name: pool-3-thread-5
State: WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2d9e6700
Total blocked: 1,747  Total waited: 7,306

Stack trace: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Last logged line:
11:53:32:769 [pool-3-thread-5] INFO  ClassC:117 - MessageC
```

The threads are blocked at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method). I read that it's just the thread waiting for a new task to process. But in this case, when the application start running thread pools are created and assigned for a task that does not end until the application is stopped. Reading the logs I can see that the thread went to that waiting state without finishing the job (MessageA, MessageB and MessageC are not the last messages to log).

I don't understand how those threads stopped doing what they were doing (at different lines of code) and entered in that waiting state.

Thank you!

Comment: Obviously, your tasks *have* ended, perhaps not “finishing” the job, so it’s time to check how you deal with exceptions thrown inside your task…

Comment: Hi Holger! I have a global catch of Exception that now I changed to Throwable just in case. A friend suggested an OutOfMemoryError could be happening and that the thread could not even print it. We simulated that error in a poc and got the application in the same state. I just need to verify this is actually the problem.

Comment: There is no such thing as a “global catch” in Java. You can use `try … catch` to catch exceptions within a local code flow or set a global handler for *uncaught* exceptions on a thread or thread group. When you `submit` a job to a thread pool executor, all exceptions of the job are caught and you have to query the returned `Future` to get the exception. Those exceptions do not show up anywhere else.

Comment: I didn't say there was a thing called "global catch". I meant that all exceptions that could be raised in the code that executes in those threads are caught and logged. The problem is actually an OOM, but the logger fails to log because it has no memory. We hinted the GC to execute (using System.gc()) before logging and OutOfMemoryError was printed!